# Can I use a keyboard shortcut to save work in Matlab on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, matlab, keyboard-shortcuts, savechanges

All Windows editing programs allow you to save your work by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>. Linux has an independently developed and mostly different set of keyboard shortcuts from what's standard in Windows. I am learning some of the Linux shortcuts as I program Matlab (by GUI, opened from BASH), but I can't find any shortcut to save the code I'm on, the equivalent of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>.

Is there anything, or in this operating system that hosts Emacs, which focuses its keyboard shortcuts on not having to move the hands at all, is the only way to save code by moving my hand to the mouse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/keyboard-shortcuts.html#br7ulae-1, you can go to:

> Preferences > MATLAB > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Active settings

and change your keyboard shortcuts to the `Windows Default Set`.